# Force local DateTime serialization

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization

I'm serializing a `DateTime` value, and it works OK, creates an `ISODateTime` value. But it is always serializing using UTC.

```
YYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm:ss
```

When I create the `DateTime` instance, I force `LocalTime`:

```
 DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks,DateTimeKind.Local);
```

But, for some reason it always serializes to UTC (I always get '+01:00' at the end). It is supposed to automatically read get `DataTimeKind` and serialize properly, but no... :(

How do I configure the serializer or the attribute to force the `DateTime` to be serialized in Local Time?

**EDIT:** This is a test class

```
[Serializable]
public class DateTimeTest
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DateTime")]
    public DateTime dateTime;
}
```

This is serialization code

```
    public static string XMLSerializeToString<ObjectType>(ObjectType objetToSerialize, string defaultNamespace)
    {
        TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializer serializer =
            defaultNamespace==null ? new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectType)) : new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectType),defaultNamespace);
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objetToSerialize);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

This is callin' the serializer

```
    DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
    DateTimeTest dateTimeTest = new DateTimeTest();
    dateTimeTest.dateTime = localDateTime;
    string ser = XMLProcessor.XMLSerializeToString<DateTimeTest>(dateTimeTest, null);
```

This is the resulting string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DateTimeTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DateTime>2013-10-25T17:01:35.7228+01:00</DateTime>
</DateTimeTest>
```

I dont want to get 17:01:35+01:00. I want to get 17:01:35. How can I get it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You haven't said what serializer you're using, but you might try setting its Kind to DateTimeKind.Unspecified if you don't want to see the timezone offset.

Comment: what do you mean by serialization? call `ToString` method?

Comment: `+01:00` means the value is not UTC, else it'd be `Z`. It's the offset of your local time relative to UTC. So I don't get your problem. You also don't describe how you serialize it.

Comment: btw. `DateTime.Now` is already returning a local `DateTime` value, so your weird way of constructing the date doesn't have any effect for most dates, but causes bugs when the local time is ambiguous due to DST switching.

Comment: For the record, you can change the `DateTime` kind without resorting to using `Ticks`. You definitely shouldn't need to change the kind to local when using `DateTime.Now` (it's already local, as CodesInChaos mentioned). To change what kind of date a `DateTime` is use the `DateTime.SpecifyKind` method.

Comment: I have updated my question by addding code. What I need is that, when serializing, It whill show my local time, not UTC plus difference to local time. I'm in UTC+1, and I want to get 17:00:00, not 16:00:00+01:00
EDIT: @Joe Thats it! Unspecified! I hadn't understand DateTimeKind :( PLease, post your comment as a solution, so I can vote for it :)
Shaamaan, thnks for SpecifyKind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment:

> You haven't said what serializer you're using, but you might try setting its Kind to DateTimeKind.Unspecified if you don't want to see the timezone offset.

Your code to set the DateTime:

```
DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

is unnecessarily unwieldly, being exactly equivalent to:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

If you want a date time that will serialize without an offset, it needs to have DateTimeKind.Unspecified:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Now.SpecifyKind(DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Comment: It's not exactly equivalent since `Now` can return both kinds of local DateTime, whereas the OP's code only returns one of them. The second kind of local datetime is required to ensure roundtrips to UTC work even with DST switches.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I think it is exactly equivalent - what do you mean by "both kinds of local DateTime"?  Since .NET 2.0, when the Kind property was introduced, DateTime.Now always returns Kind = Local (while of course DateTime.UtcNow returns Kind = Utc).

Comment: `DateTime` only exposes one kind of `Local`, but internally stores two. That internally stored one is used to disambiguate times during the DST switch where e.g. "2:30 local" exists twice. This means you can obtain two `DateTime` values with `Kind == Local` that look identical, but produce different times when converted to UTC.